# Socket response issue

Tags: ios, swift

I have five tab in my app. The second tab is shown after login and I have called socket connect in viewDidAppear of third tab as shown below.

```
SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.connectToServer(decoded, completionHandler: { (List) -> Void in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    print("response \(List)")
)}
)
```

And in SocketIOManager the below code

```
func connectToServer(data: AnyObject, completionHandler: (List: AnyObject) -> Void) {
    socket.on("connect") { (dataArray, socketAck) -> Void in
        self.socket.emit("api_request", data)
        print("Socket Connected")
    }
    socket.on("api_response") { ( dataArray, ack) -> Void in
        completionHandler(List: dataArray as AnyObject!)
        //print("acknowledgemt received from \(dataArray)")

    }

}
```

And in Appdelegate the below code

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

        SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.closeConnection()
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

        SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.establishConnection()
}
```

I'm not getting the response as soon as I login and press the third tab. Getting the response only after closing the app and reopening it.

Comment: You need to provide more code of the app. Also screenshots or a more clear steps what happens would be helpful

Comment: @Alistra i tried putting breakpoint on socket.emit it is getting emitted but on socket.on("api_response") I'm not getting response